# Dbms_Output.Put_Line not printing inside inner functions/procedures

Tags: oracle, function, oracle-sqldeveloper, procedures, dbms-output

I am running a PL/SQL anonymous block on SQL developer that calls some functions /procedures (which in turn call other functions/procedures) .... the outer block contains some Dbms_Output.Put_Line statements as well as the called functions/procedures .... the Dbms_Output.Put_Line statements in the outer block works well and gives output while the inner doesn't print anything.
Any help ?

```
 set serveroutput on;
 DECLARE
 p_comIds CM.NUM_ARRAY; --a table type
 --declare some variables
 BEGIN
   p_comIds  :=cm.NUM_ARRAY();
   p_comIds.EXTEND;
   p_comIds(p_comIds.LAST) := 18508781;
   cm.someProcedure(p_comIds); --contains Dbms_Output.put_line
  Dbms_Output.Put_Line('this prints'); -this prints
END;
```

Comment: Do you see output from the outer block even after the functions/procedures have been called? If not maybe one of those is disabling it. Please show a demo anonymous block which calls the same functions /procedures and has output before and after those, along with the output you actually get when you execute it.

Comment: What Alex said. You can use the debugger to step through the outer to inner block to confirm that your code is even being called or not.

Comment: output prints even after functions calls, debugging not working , code has nothing special ... sure

Comment: Then it seems more likely that the bug (logical error) is in the inner functions/procedures, not in the outer function. Can you show the inner procedure?